# Installation type step of installation process doesn't display any options

Tags: boot, dual-boot, dell

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a Dell XPS 13 9380 that came with Windows 10 pre-installed. I have followed instructions from Dell (https://www.dell.com/support/article/uk/en/ukdhs1/sln301754/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-windows-8-or-10-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en). Everthing seems ok, until I get to the installation type step, when I'm not presented with any options (such as "Install Ubuntu along with Windows" or "Erase disk and install Ubuntu").

Following advice on another post here, I have installed and run the boot-repair tool. It provides the following URL: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8WPHqSj2z4/

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'd missed one or more step(s), I think the key one being switching from SATA from RAID to AHCI, as described here: http://jkssweetlife.com/dual-boot-windows-10-ubuntu/.

I guess this counts as my first successful use of StackExchange, although I'm slightly disappointed that I solved the problem myself!